# Apache2 PHP5 timeout setting?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, timeout

I have a long script to run, as cron, in PHP. I'm calling the script locally using wget from a cron job, but it fails after 15 minutes.

In apache2.conf, I have configured Timeout to 12000
In php.ini, I have configured max_execution_time to 72000

Despite those settings, wget fails after exactly 15 minutes...

Is there any other place where I need to change a setting ?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with all packages up to date (Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3).

Thank you

Comment: Error message shown by wget: Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wget?...what this script is actually doing? When your cron gets executed, have you checked apache/php threads in memory?

Comment: The script is in PHP, I'm passing some arguments through the page address. It's browsing through 1 TB of picture files and creating categories and tags for each. Memory seems to be all right, I'm running Munin and it's barely starting to swap.

Comment: You pointing WGET helped a lot - it has a default timeout of 900 seconds. wget -T allows the user to extend the duration before a timeout. Thank you !